# OneSignal SDK - ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: vue.js, push-notification, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, onesignal

I'm trying to setup push notifications in a Nuxt 3 PWA app with OneSignal, but can't get it to work.
After following [the quickstart guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-quickstart) for web I get ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT in both Brave and Chrome.

```
// /public/OneSignalSDKWorker.js

importScripts("https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/web/v16/OneSignalSDK.sw.js");
```

```
// index.vue
import { useOneSignal } from '@onesignal/onesignal-vue3'

export default {
    setup() {
        const Onesignal = useOneSignal().init({
            appId: appID    
        })
    }

}
```

If I go to brave://settings/content/braveShields and turn off shields for localhost:3000
the prompt asking to allow notifications is displayed. But after clicking "allow", I get this:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLBt0.png)

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/web/v16/OneSignalSDK.sw.js' failed to load.

The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
```